# Finding program code in memory with C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

If I have a string formatting program in C, that consists of only one file, is it possible to find where that file resides in memory and let the running program process its own source file?

When a C program runs, is it possible to define a pointer that points to the actual code and process that?

I don't want to open and read the source file, but do it from memory.

Comment: So basically, you want to include the source of your program in the compiled executable binary and then reference it somehow, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I have correctly understood the question, but I give it a try:

You can access to the pathname of the source file of your C software with the `__FILE__` directive. Using it for purposes other than displaying it implies that it has not moved or disappeared since the last compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually C is compiled before running. This means that the source code is translated to executable machine instructions. So the source code is probably not available in memory when you run the program.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean your program analyses machine code? Or C source?

Your C program, once it's compiled, is not in C anymore so the running program will be in machine code, not C.

Why don't you want to open the source file from disk?

Answer (score 0):

> When a C program runs, is it possible to define a pointer that points to the actual code and process that?

I suppose you could take the address of a function by using a function pointer, and read/write by casting it to an integer pointer. However, this would be highly unusual, difficult and dangerous for numerous reasons. For writing code, the machine code could be in a read-only section of memory. Moreover, you'd have to write machine code to memory.